# Pointer arrays?

Tags: arrays, pointers

Any way to count number of words in the following pointer arrays?

```
#include<iostream.h>        
void main()
{    
 char *city[2]={"America","England"};
 while(city[0]!='\0')
   {
       count++;
   }
  cout<<count;
}
```

If one get address of A then it can be possible, but how to access address of 'A'- of America.

By doing all the following i could able to fetch the address of ptr array not A.

```
 cout<<&city[0]<<endl;
 cout<<&city<<endl;
 cout<<city<<endl;
 cout<<city[0]<<endl;
 cout<<*(&city[0])<<endl;
 cout<<&(*city)<<endl;        // Question ??? Again address of ptr.
```

Help me out.

Comment: Think about it... It's `&city[0][0]`.

Comment: Form a useful title, dude!

Comment: Thanks H2CO3 ... the best answer by you..

Answer (score 1):

You can count number of chars in string because it ends with '\0'. But static array is not a string.

You can't count the size of static array. You have to introduce a variable to store it.

If you do not want to introduce additional variable I recommend to use std::vector instead of array: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

```
#include<iostream.h>        
void main()
{    
  std::vector<char *> city(2);
  city[0] = "America";
  city[1] = "England";
  const int count = city.size();
  cout<<count;
}
```